# How to make DOM manipulation work on SPA view change and load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I am currently working on a single page application (following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/js-vanilla-script-spa-1b29b43ea475)) and face two obstacles.

1. When changing the view of the SPA I try to execute functions and manipulate some elements (CSS, Text etc.) when the hash is changing and the location hash equals the mentioned names. **Problem**: it doesn't change the elements as expected. It appears to a problem with the views loading, because I was able to make changes to the whole body, like changing the background color. But not to the views the router is loading into a div with id app.
2. **Solved**. *As a function, it does not execute when reloading the app.*

   ```
   window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e){
   if(location.hash=='#profile')
   {
     console.log('#profile');
   }
   else if(location.hash=='#cvedit')
   {
     console.log('#cvedit');    
   }
   else if(location.hash=='#poll')
   {
     console.log('#poll');
     $("#question_text").css("color","blue");
     $("#question_text").text("Where's Waldo?");
   }
   else if(location.hash=='#about')
   {
     console.log('#about');

   }
   else if(location.hash='#home')
   {
     console.log('#home');
   }})
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When you reload the page browser does not fire `hashchange` event ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event)), that's why your code is not working as supposed to. You can use `DOMContentLoaded` event to catch reloads.

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', yourCallbackFunction)
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', yourCallbackFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure, this is what I thought is the problem. But I didn't know of DOMContentLoaded. 
Do you probably have a solution for the other issue with DOM manipulation of loaded HTML?